# Arch linux WSL AUR

Tags: arch-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I get AUR builds working in WSL.

Essentially I always get Permission denied (os error 13) as I am not running as root

But you can't use AUR as root user so catch 22.

Example transactions showing as root and local

```
    [root@DannysLaptop ~]# paru -S system-monitoring-center
:: Resolving dependencies...
error: can't install AUR package as root
[root@DannysLaptop ~]# su danny
[danny@DannysLaptop root]$ paru -S system-monitoring-center
:: Resolving dependencies...
:: Calculating conflicts...
:: Calculating inner conflicts...

Repo (8) dmidecode-3.3-1  startup-notification-0.12-7  libxres-1.2.1-1  libwnck3-40.0-1  mesa-utils-8.4.0-7  python-cairo-1.20.1-3  freeglut-3.2.2-1  python-opengl-3.1.5-6
Aur (1) system-monitoring-center-1.2.1-1

:: Proceed to review? [Y/n]: 

:: Downloading PKGBUILDs...
 PKGBUILDs up to date
 nothing new to review
error: failed to run: sudo pacman --sync -- extra/dmidecode extra/startup-notification extra/libxres extra/libwnck3 extra/mesa-utils extra/python-cairo extra/freeglut extra/python-opengl: Permission denied (os error 13)
[danny@DannysLaptop root]$
```

Comment: Are you using an AUR helper like `yay` or `paru`? Can you post the entire transaction where you get the error (add to your question, please)?

Comment: Added requested output using paru btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NotTheDr01ds for pointing out that this was a Rust-based error.
Switching to `yay` (based on Go instead of Rust) has side-stepped this issue for me and is working perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear that pointed you in the right direction.  I think some reviewers thought this sounded more like a comment than an answer (thus the downvote), but I disagree (and have upvoted).  Using different software to workaround an issue is a completely acceptable solution.  I've edited your answer (pending approval) to make it sound less like a comment and more like an answer.  However, please self-accept your answer so that this question gets "closed out".  Otherwise, the system automatically "bumps" questions that don't have an accepted answer randomly at some point in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing appears to be related to a permissions issue of some sort with Rust.  See [this Github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6757) for some possible insight.  Note that I was able to install and run `paru` on Arch under WSL2 with no issue myself while trying to replicate your issue.

Is there anything unusual in your WSL2/Arch home directory?  I could see this potentially happening if `/home/danny/.cargo` was on a Windows drive, for instance.  Or is there any file or directory in `/home/danny/.cargo` or `/home/danny/.rustup` that is owned by root?